# Angular type of Components

Tags: angular, typescript, type-safety

I have a `routesList` that I use in the app-routing.module of Angular
The type of the `routesList` is:

```js
type routesList = {
  [key: string]: {
    path: string;
    title: string;
    component: Type<Component>;
  };
};
```

The current list that is being exported is:

```js
export const routesList: routesList = {
  home: {
    path: '',
    title: 'Curation Console',
    component: AppComponent,
  },
  otherpage: {
    path: 'otherpage',
    title: 'Other Page',
    component: OtherPageComponent,
  },
};
```

But I'm getting an error for `component: AppComponent` saying

```
typescript: Type of 'typeof AppComponent' is not assignable to type 'Type<Component>'.
Type 'AppComponent' has no properties in common with type 'Component'.
```

Is the `Type<Component>` incorrect for this use?
Is there another way I could get the type of Angular Components?

Comment: Why are you providing type<Component> for component when its a route the component stands for the path component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robby had covers the details of how/why `Type<any>` would solve the problem. Here is another way of doing it.

Instead defining your own type similar to `Route`(@angular/router) type. Use the existing `Route` interface.

```
type routesList = {
  [key: string]: Route
};
```

---

```
type routerList = Record<string, Route>;
```

Answer (score 2):

The type used for a component in a [`Route`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) by Angular is `Type<any>`, so defining your `routesList` as follows should be OK:

```
type routesList = {
  [key: string]: {
    path: string;
    title: string;
    component: Type<any>;
  };
};
```

If you want to narrow that down to a custom base class you're using for your components (e.g. `Type<MyComponentBase>`), you can, but [`Component`](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) is *not* that base class. It's an interface that is used as a decorator to mark components as components, and your own component classes almost certainly do not conform to that interface.

Instead of defining your own `routesList` type, it's probably better to just use [the one provided by Angular](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes), and extend that one if needed.